# Someone to help me with my Htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, paypal

I have the following code into the htaccess file of my joomla website:

```
## Back-end protection
## This also blocks fingerprinting attacks browsing for XML and INI files
RewriteRule ^administrator/?$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^administrator/index\.(php|html?)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^administrator/index[23]\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^administrator/(components|modules|templates|images|plugins)/([^/]+/)*   ([^/.]+\.)+(jp(e?g|2)?|png|gif|bmp|css|js|swf|html?|mp(eg?|[34])|avi|wav|og[gv]|xlsx?|docx?|pptx?|zip|rar|pdf|xps|txt|7z|svg|od[tsp]|flv|mov)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^administrator/ - [F]
```

Since I added this code to my htaccess file I've been dealing with problems with the notifications from Paypal via the script notify.php. I'm checking the following code to try to allow notify.php be working in my site with no success.

```
## Allow PayPal Notify
#RewriteRule ^/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/(notify\.php)?$ - [L]
```

¿Could you kindly help me to find a solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one?

```
# Allow PayPal Notify
RewriteRule ^/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/notify\.php - [L]
```

Place the above lines directly above your last rewrite rule

If this doesn't work, post some lines from your apache error.log showing some failed requests from paypal.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but it doesn't work. Thanks! Any other friend who knows how to fix it?